# Experiencing "IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" from Local Machine

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am getting the below Exception while connecting Oracle Server, though there are many posts related to this question. I am posting this especially because with the below config all other team member is able to connect but only from my system it is not working.

Please help me to resolve this , I am struggling a lot for the past two days.

## EXCEPTION :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at OracleTest.main(OracleTest.java:19)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:214)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided enough details
Can you provide the connection string, which database version you are connecting to?

For now you can check these things

1. Can you ping the host database server ip? Please check that first.
2. Check what jdk version you are using, are you using jdk 1.7?

Comment: Thanks for a quick response.. Please find the details

Comment: Where are the details?